# Unable to use apt-get on Ubuntu 12.04 Virtual Machine

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, openssh

My ubuntu was working just fine but today it has started giving me problems. I am not able to use apt-get. there is some openssh dependency issue. I tried to solve by reading forums but I could not resolve my problem.
This is what i get when i try: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
Output:

```
Setting up openssh-server (1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.8) ...
/etc/init.d/ssh: 33: exec: /lib/init/upstart-job: Permission denied
invoke-rc.d: initscript ssh, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
```

Please help me out as I am totally stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, and you are not dependant on ssh (you have physical access to the machine), try uninstalling openssh-server, updating and then reinstalling:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client --purge && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```